# Clearing DataGridView bound to DataSet without losing headers VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I've currently got an application that you can search for a specific location, owner, etc. which will return some basic information about the device(s).  I have this information pulled via a SQL query and placed into a DataSet which is then placed into a DataGridView object.  I am trying to implement a Clear button which will remove the search terms as well as the data in the DataGridView object.

Unfortunately, I cannot use  `DataGridView.Rows.Clear()` as my DataGridView is bound to a DataSet.  I am running into difficulty using `DataGridView.DataSource = Nothing` as this is not only removing the data that was displayed, but also removes my headers for columns that I have created for the DataGridView.  I have tried a few solutions I've found such as `DataGridView.Refresh()` and `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false` but these have thus far removed the column headers.

This is the code I am using for adding rows to the DataGridView object;

```
    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(getConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT asset.assetID, owner.ownerName, model.brand, asset.modelID, deviceOwner.serialNumber, deviceOwner.location, asset.dateAssessed from asset 
                                  join deviceOwner on asset.assetID = deviceOwner.assetID
                                  join owner on deviceOwner.ownerID = owner.OwnerID
                                  join model on asset.modelID = model.modelID where asset.dateAssessed = @checkDate", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkDate", searchEnterDate.Text.ToString)
        con.Open()
        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "MyTable")
        displayResults.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable").DefaultView
        con.Close()
        con = Nothing
```

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to clear the rows from the DataGridView without removing the column headers so I can use the clear button if necessary but continue to search with column headers still displaying.

Comment: How about creating a DataTable with just the column headers and assign it as your DataSource when you want to "blank" it?

Comment: If the col headers are the same it means the query may essentially the same, just filtered.  Rather than running a new query you could try to use the `DefaultView.RowFilter`.

Comment: I  use a DataView derived from the DataTable and set the filter as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) the `DataTable` which keeps columns but "removes" data:

```
Dim oldTable As DataTable = CType(displayResults.DataSource, DataView).Table
Dim emptyTable As DataTable = oldTable.Clone()
displayResults.DataSource = emptyTable ' or emptyTable.DefaultView
```

or use  [`DataRowCollection.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) on the old table which could cause more side-effects:

```
oldTable.Rows.Clear()
```

Comment: Clone was what I was thinking. Good idea.

Comment: This fit my needs perfectly.  Thanks for the help!  It gives me some errors if the dataTable is already blank, but I can work on error handling for this!